# DBMS_REDEFINITION with WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, partitioning, dbms-redefinition

I wanted to know if DBMA_REDEFINITON package allows a WHERE clause to filter contents before migration.

I have a partitioned table and wants to copy data and constraint to another table using DBMA_REDEFINITON but while copying contents, I do not want to copy a particular partition from the original table. Is it possible to drop this partition using WHERE clause.

The question came from following information given on [Oracle Tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_fastest_delete_from_large_table.htm) site

`Online table redefinition:  You can drop large numbers of rows from a table by adding a WHERE clause predicate to filter-out unwanted rows when you copy the table.`

My requirement is from the example below, can a new table have only partitions Part_2 and Part3. (Dropping partition Part_1 using WHERE clause)

```
-- Existing Table
CREATE TABLE ORIGINAL
(
  ID                INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TEXT              VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL
)PARTITION BY RANGE
  (
    ID
  )
  (
    PARTITION part_1 VALUES LESS THAN(2),
    PARTITION part_2 VALUES LESS THAN(3),
    PARTITION part_3 VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
  )
/
-- some data in the table
insert into ORIGINAL values (1, 'test');

-- some index on the table
create index idx_ORIGINAL on ORIGINAL(TEXT);

--INTERIM table for REDEFINITION (has all partitions right now)
CREATE TABLE ORIGINAL_INTERIM
(
  ID                INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TEXT              VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE
  (
    ID
  )
  (
    PARTITION part_1 VALUES LESS THAN(2),
    PARTITION part_2 VALUES LESS THAN(3),
    PARTITION part_3 VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
  )
/

-- Start Redefinition
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('TSPACE1','ORIGINAL','ORIGINAL_INTERIM');
END;
/


-- Copy objects
DECLARE
  num_errors PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS ('TSPACE1','ORIGINAL','ORIGINAL_INTERIM',
    DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_ORIG_PARAMS, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, num_errors);
END;
/


-- Sync
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.SYNC_INTERIM_TABLE ('TSPACE1','ORIGINAL','ORIGINAL_INTERIM');
END;
/

-- finish
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE ('TSPACE1','ORIGINAL','ORIGINAL_INTERIM');
END;
/

-- Drop interim table
drop table ORIGINAL_INTERIM cascade constraints purge;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `part_name` parameter of `DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE` procedure. Here is the complete example of online table redefinition. [Online Table Redefinition Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#CJABBFDH) from Oracle Docs.
[Methods to move a partition to another tablespace](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11444.methods-to-move-a-partition-to-another-tablespace)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, but unfortunately it looks like with PART_NAME I can only redefine with single partition. My requirement was to skip a single partition and copy rest of the partitions. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: @Sauchin If you want to move selected partition then use `ALTER TABLE MOVE PARTITION` else if you want to redefine table with selected partitions then  use `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION`.

Comment: Yes I should be using either move or drop partition statements, but both involve rebuilding global indexes which currently takes a lot of time due to TB of data. Also within that period depending upon the option chosen I risk either locking the tables until index is rebuilt `(ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION REBUILD GLOBAL INDEXES)` or failing DML with UNUSABLE indexes issue `(ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION; ALTER INDEX REBUILD ONLINE)`. This was my desperate attempt to avoid both :) ... I appreciate your help.

Comment: Though this answer does not solve my problem completely, I am accepting this answer as this is the closest solution you can get as far as the question is concerned.